# Django based invoice web app suggestion for novice

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-forms

I am new to Django and I am making an order management web application for a local food corner. What I want is to take orders from a webpage and further process the data for the store. I am struggling with capturing the data from the web page. In the attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abeCn.png), if I type 'The Orio Doughnut' and the quantity, the unit price should be extracted from the database and the line total should be calculated automatically by multiplying the quantity*unit price. After the order has been created by 'continue to checkout' how can I capture this data to the backend? I do not need the code. I just need the steps for this task including what should be done by js and what should be by Django.

Comment: Where's the code? What have you tried?

Comment: I have created the models and forms. But I have no clue to implement the form in this HTML form I have attached in the image. have you seen the screenshot of my HTML form?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, please view [how to write effective questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking another question.